# Integrating $ \int^1_0 dx \frac{\ln(x-a)}{x-b} $, paying attention to cuts.

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, contour-integration, branch-cuts

I am trying to compute the following integral, for complex $a$ and $b$
$$
\int^1_0 dx \frac{\ln(x-a)}{x-b}
$$
by turning it into something in terms of dilogarithms.  But for certain values of $a$ and $b$ the logarithmic cut gets in the way, and is impeding my progress.  **I need help with keeping track of the cut** in my computation.

I've tried to take this step by step, checking myself against a numerical integration carried out using Mathematica.

My steps are as follows:

1. Shift integration variables $x\rightarrow x+a$:
   $$I = \int_{-a}^{1-a}dx\frac{\ln(x)}{x+a-b}$$
2. Split integration (according to Mathematica, **this is NOT correct** for all $a$ and $b$):
   $$I = \int_{0}^{1-a}dx\frac{\ln(x)}{x+a-b}-\int_{-0}^{-a}dx\frac{\ln(x)}{x+a-b}$$
3. In each term rescale the integral: $x\rightarrow (1-a)x$ in the first integral, $x\rightarrow-a x$ in the second.
   $$I=\int_0^1 dx \frac{\ln((1-a)x)}{x+\frac{a-b}{1-a}}-\int_0^1 dx \frac{\ln(-a x)}{x-\frac{a-b}{a}}$$
4. Next, write the denominators as derivatives of logarithms $1/(x+\lambda)=\frac{d}{dx}\ln(1+x/\lambda)$
   $$\int_0^1 dx \frac{d}{dx} \Big[\ln\Big(\frac{1-a}{a-b}x+1\Big)\Big]\ln((1-a)x)+\int_0^1 dx \frac{d}{dx} \Big[\ln\Big(\frac{-a}{a-b}x+1\Big)\Big]\ln{(-ax)}$$
5. Perform a partial integration
   $$I=-\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x}\ln\Big(1+\frac{1-a}{a-b}x\Big)+\Big[\ln\Big(1+\frac{1-a}{a-b}x\Big)\ln((1-a)x)\Big]^1_0\\
   +\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x}\ln\Big(1+\frac{-a}{a-b}x\Big)+\Big[\ln\Big(1+\frac{-a}{a-b}x\Big)\ln(-ax)\Big]^1_0$$
6. Convert to dilogarithms:
   $$I=\text{Li}_2\Big(\frac{-1+a}{a-b}\Big)-\text{Li}_2\Big(\frac{a}{a-b}\Big)+\ln\Big(1+\frac{1-a}{a-b}\Big)\ln(1-a)-\ln\Big(1-\frac{a}{a-b}\Big)\ln(-a)$$

But this expression is not true for any complex values of $a$ and $b$.  How do I modify my analysis to take into account of the logarithmic cut?